# Discord.py on_reaction_remove() not firing when reaction is revoked

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a form of reaction roles for my discord bot, when you react with the pikachu emoji your `user.id` will be added to `joined`

Now, originally I wanted your `user.id` to be removed when you un-react but I soon realized that `on_reaction_remove()` wasn't even being fired. I tried multiple methods I found on the internet but none of them worked.

This is something I made to represent the problem.

```
channel = client.get_channel(782978946735407154)
ga = await channel.send(embed=em4)
await ga.add_reaction(f"<:pikachu:837851420027125760>")

joined = []

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if user != client.user:  # and user != ctx.author
        if str(reaction.emoji) == f"<:pikachu:837851420027125760>":
            lvl = await mee6API.levels.get_user_level(user.id)
            if int(lvl) >= int(''.join(map(str, level))):
                joined.append(user.id)
                print("reaction added")
            else:
                # await reaction.remove(user)
                print("Placeholder")

@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
    if user != client.user:  # and user != ctx.author
        if str(reaction.emoji) == f"<:pikachu:837851420027125760>":
            print("reaction removed")
```

Answer (score 0):

`on_reaction_add` only works on internally cached messages, while `on_raw_reaction_add` works regardless of the state of internally cached messages.

Here's what you can use:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload): 
    member = payload.member
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    #rest of your code here
```

Documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add

Comment: See I want it too detect when it removes the reaction.

Comment: Incorrect, `on_reaction_add` and `on_raw_reaction_add` are two same yet different things.

Comment: @Lloyd your post also says that `on_reaction_add` isn't working for you..
You could try `on_raw_reaction_remove` for detecting when a reaction is removed.

@Rose I've edited my post as per the documentation, for the difference between the two. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I meant ```on_reaction_remove()```